# Pandas copied object is changed after modifying the copy

Tags: python, pandas, copy, deep-copy

I have a DataFrame `test` with a DateTimeIndex and I want to create a copy and drop the frequency
on the copy. But the original `test` also losses information about the frequency. I used `test.copy(deep=True)` to make sure I make a deep copy.

```python
import copy
import pandas as pd

dr = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', periods=10, freq='1H')
test = pd.DataFrame({'target':list(range(10))}, index=dr)
print(test.index.freq)
>>> <Hour>
_copy = test.copy(deep=True)
# _copy = copy.deepcopy(test)
print(test.index.freq)
>>> <Hour>
_copy.index.freq=None
print(test.index.freq)
>>> None # expectet output is <Hour>
```

In a second step I created my copy using `copy.deepcopy(test)` but the result is still the same.

I am using pandas 1.3.3 and python 3.9.7.

Is there an option to create a copy not linked to the original?

Comment: Please post the expected output as well.

Comment: `_copy = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(test))` seems working

Comment: code works if I do also `_copy.index = copy.deepcopy(test.index)`